# Missing UTF8 as document class, conflicts with .sty-file. How can I add UTF8?

Tags: document-classes

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I have tried several different solutions but none work. I have a custom class that I need to write a document in. This class automatically generate some pages with UTF8-encoding (needed for Swedish letters). When I try to compile with

```
\documentclass[utf8,...]{rtthesis}
```

I get too many errors to list here, the main point is that the document class "utf8" is missing. I can replace it with latin1, but this breaks the Swedish characters. I can use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

which compiles, but breaks the Swedish characters in the front page. I'm out of ideas what to try here, and hope that someone has come across a similar problem before.

Thanks for any help,

Niclas

Comment: In `\documentclass[utf8,…]{rtthesis}` the `utf8` is an option, not a document class. As I don't know that document class, could you please check the error messagen?

Comment: Are you sure your document is saved with UTF-8 encoding? This concerns *input* rather than *output*. What editor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `latex`, you can try `xelatex`, which uses the `xetex` engine which runs on utf8 tex-files. In this case, you should probably delete the `utf8`-option in your documentclass and you have no need for and should avoid `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages.

Comment: I am using xelatex as typesetting engine. The error I'm getting is: (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)

`./main.tex:17: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...` And variations thereof. I can't delete the utf8 option, since the custom document class I'm using expects either utf8 or latin1 there.

Comment: Try commenting out `inputenc`. There should be no need for it anyway, when using `xelatex`.

Comment: For further oddities, I've found that the file compiles fine in TeXShop but not Texpad. Changing typesetting engine from xelatex in Texpad solves the problem, and everything compiles fine. I do not know error source yet. Inputenc is not included, only utf8 in the first documentclass header.

Comment: I guess that the reason why it compiles in a different editor/IDE is because the other IDE calls `xelatex` with different options. As for `inputenc`, it is probably required and loaded by the class, which is why the `utf8` option can be passed to the `\documentclass` command. This option-passing mechanism is common in custom classes, for example `babel` language options can be passed via the `\documentclass` command with the [`ulthese`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulthese) class. If the class is meant to be processed with `xelatex`, loading `inputenc` *in the class* is a design oversight.